# R - Convert Integer to 8-bit binary

Tags: r

I have a 3 dimension array that represents RGB values from 0 to 255. I would like to convert each element of this array into an 8-bit binary value, including trailing/leading zeros.

I can use the `inToBits()` function to create a binary string using 32-bits, but I'm trying to have 8-bits only, with the format `0= '00000000'` and `255= '11111111'`

```
#2x2 array of RGB values
ints <- array(as.integer(c(1,100,255,143,10,12,14,55,15,84,31,96)), dim=c(2,2,3))

#Convert array into a binary string. Expect size of 2*2*3*32.
bit.32 <- paste0(as.character(intToBits(ints)),collapse = "")
```

My desired output would be:
'1000000001001101111111111110001'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this ?

```
toBinary <- function(n){
  paste0(as.integer(rev(intToBits(n)[1:8])), collapse = "")
}

> toBinary(255)
[1] "11111111"
> toBinary(128)
[1] "10000000"
```